# CanvasJS labels are wrongly positioned

Tags: canvasjs

I'm using CanvasJS to display some weather data, but the labels seem to have the wrong position relative to their data point.

What is the cause of this?

[image]

This is my chart configuration:

```js
animationEnabled: true,
        exportEnabled: true,
        title: {
            text: 'Pronóstico 8 Días',
        },
        axisX: {
            valueFormatString: 'DD MMM,YYYY',
            labelAngle: -30,
            labelPlacement: 'outside',
            labelTextAlign: 'left',
        },
        axisY: {
            title: 'Temperatura',
            suffix: ' °C',
            minimum: 18,
            maximum: 40,
            interval: 2,
        },
        data: [
            {
                name: 'Mínimas',
                type: 'line',
                yValueFormatString: '#0.## °C',
                showInLegend: true,
                indexLabelWrap: true,
                indexLabelMaxWidth: 80,
                dataPoints: min,
            },
            {
                name: 'Máximas',
                type: 'line',
                yValueFormatString: '#0.## °C',
                showInLegend: true,
                indexLabelWrap: true,
                indexLabelMaxWidth: 80,
                dataPoints: max,
            },
        ],
```

Comment: It seems like dataPoints passed vary in time component i.e. hours/minutes. If you change xValueFormatString to "DD MM YYYY hh:mm" and valueFormatString: to 'DD MMM,YYYY hh:mm', you can clearly observe the difference among them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the dates were shifting because they included time, so I just turned into day/month/year only.